# Is assuming independence of errors equivalent to assuming residuals and predicted values are independent?

Tags: regression, independence

The [Penn State STAT200 course](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/book/export/html/244#:%7E:text=Independence%20of%20errors%3A%20There%20is,residuals%20and%20the%20predicted%20values.) states that assuming that the errors are independent is equivalent to assuming that residuals $\hat{\epsilon}$ and predicted values $\hat{y}$ are not related, which I take to mean - independent. I guess this is not obvious to me. I would love to see a mathematical proof as well as intuition as to why this is the case.

[image]

Comment: That is an error in the presentation. The actual independence of errors assumption is not related to what the materials show, at least not in any direct way.  What they present is somewhat related to the linearity and constant variance assumptions, although not in the sense that the linear correlation should be zero, because it is automatically zero.

Comment: Thank you. Your position makes sense and I agree with it. I think that while without the assumption of error independence we cannot conclude that $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{\epsilon}$  are independent (only that they are uncorrelated), the assumption of error independence without the assumption that the errors are Normally distributed is not enough to conclude that $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{\epsilon}$ are independent.

Comment: The quotation incorrectly conflates "residuals" and "errors."  It is part of a chapter (#12) in a course on regression.  Several pages in that chapter are glaringly incorrect (see https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/12/12.6 for instance, which misinterprets two of the diagnostic plots).

Comment: @whuber: I see. Thank you. My question started as a curiosity but it is becoming clear this is a misstatement on their part, in that among other things, they use the words "residual" and "error" interchangeably.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, the independence assumption of the errors is this: The random variables $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$ are mutually independent. This can be checked using time series plots of residuals with time series data. With repeated measures data, you can estimate intraclass correlations.  With spatial data, you can estimate spatial dependence parameters.  All of which is a far cry from the suggestion given in the materials.